# Remote Docker engine in PhpStorm Services

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I can't find any information if I can use PhpStorm Services with Docker Engine installed on the remote server.

I know I can use `docker context` command to switch between local and remote Docker Engine, and it works fine for me but I want to integrate PhpStorm too to improve my work.

Is it even possible to connect PhpStorm to the remote Docker in this way?

Comment: Search for Docker in settings.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be possible at the moment. We have [this request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202233), but frankly, I think proper Docker contexts support deserves a separate one